# How can i use SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 proxies with aiohttp ClientSession?

Tags: python, python-3.6, aiohttp

How can i use SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 proxies with aiohttp ClientSession? Need some small example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried aiosocks ?

```
import asyncio
import aiosocks
from aiosocks.connector import SocksConnector

conn = SocksConnector(proxy=aiosocks.Socks5Addr(PROXY_ADDRESS, PROXY_PORT), proxy_auth=None, remote_resolve=True)
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn)
async with session.get('http://python.org') as resp:
    assert resp.status == 200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about aiosocks.